# Show previous data after AJAX request, using "go back" button in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, browser-history

I'm building application with jquery on frontend, django as rest service for database requests and tornado webosckets, to notify users, if another user has changed model.

I have simplified all listed code.
Suppose, i have next django model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def serialize(self):
        return {'pk': self.pk,
                'name': self.name,
                'description': self.description,
                'price': self.price}
```

Views, which responses with json data.

```
class ItemView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(pk=pk)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'success', 'message': None, 'data': item.serialize()}))
        except Item.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'error', 'message': 'invalid item id', 'data': None}))

class ItemsView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        items = Item.objects.all()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'success', 'message': '', 'data': [x.serialize() for x in items]}))
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ItemView.as_view(), name='item'),
    url(r'^items/$', ItemsView.as_view(), name='items')
]
```

Let the html page be with one empty element:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

On first page load i'm using ajax request to load and render all items:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/items/',
        method: 'get',
        success: function(response){
            var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response),
                status = parsedResponse.status,
                message = parsedResponse.message,
                data = parsedResponse.data;
            if (status == "success") {
                $("#main").html(""); // clear page data
                for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    $("#main").append(data[i].name);
                    $("#main").append("<a href=/item/'"+data[i].pk+" class='item-details'>Details</a>");
            } else if (status == "error"){
                $("#error").append(message);
            }
        }
    });
```

For each rendered item i have next handler to show item details. And in this case, all previously rendered items, must disappear from page:

```
$("#main").on("click", ".item-details", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        method: "get",
        success: function(response){
            var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response),
                status = parsedResponse.status,
                message = parsedResponse.message,
                data = parsedResponse.data;
            if (status == "success") {
                $("#main").html(""); // clear page data
                $("#main").append(data.name);
                $("#main").append(data.description);
                $("#main").append(data.price);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

And here i have faced with problem, after rendering item details, i dont know, how to get back to "previous" page with all items. This app shouldn't reload page. Could you advice me in my problem please, how to implement "back" function?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you send a lot of data to a user, if you have the ability to keep them, then do it. It will reduce the number of HTTP requests, number of database requests and improve user experience with a faster navigation. Instead of replacing each time `#main` html content. Keep html where you rendered all items in a div inside `#main` that you hide when the user click on an item, this one is loaded in a div next to the other in `#main`. When the user close the item, you show all items:

```html
<div id="main-div">
    <div class="items"></div>
    <div class="item-detail"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use a modal window to display details of your item and let the '#main' div visible and you just add a new div when the user request the item and remove it when he close the model window.

2. You can also copy the html content of `#main` div before replace it with the new data of item and when he close the item, you replace the html content of `#main` div with previous data but I think the solution 1 is better (performance) and cleaner.